# Split String and save to list of objects

Tags: java, string, arraylist, stringtokenizer

I have a String that I want to split from a Stringbuffer and save it into an arraylist of object.

I have a string of data that looks something like this:

```
001>10102011>874837>Y>Y>TEST001>No\\002>11102011>8743834>Y>Y>null>No\\
```

The \ will represent to save to a new object.
How do I save this string into List listsaveobj?

My sample save object is

```
public class SaveObject{
    private String obj1;
    private String obj2;
    private String obj3;
    private String obj4;
    private String obj5;
    private String obj6;
    private String obj7;

    //getters and setters
}
```

I am stuck with

```
    StringTokenizer st= new StringTokenizer(sb1.toString(),"\\\\");
        int count = 0;
        int total= st.countTokens();//count no of rows of data
        System.out.println(total);

        while(count<total){
            while(st.hasMoreElements()){
                tmpList.add(st.nextToken());
                count++;
            }
        }

              System.out.println(tmpList.size());

        for(int j = 0; j<tmpList.size(); j++){
            String str = tmpList.get(j);

            StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(str, ">");
            while (st2.hasMoreElements()){

                System.out.println(st2.nextToken());
                            // is it possible to save into ArrayList of objects here?
                            // I can see that the String can split into
                           // 001
                           // 10102011
                           // 874873
                           // Y
                           // Y
                           // TEST001
                           // No etc
                           /* using st.nextToken but I don't know how to continue from here. Pls help!! Thanks. I want to do something like
                          obj = new Object();
                          obj.saveObj1(...);
                          obj.saveObj2(...);
                          obj.saveObj3(...);
                          obj.saveObj4(...);
                          obj.saveObj5(...);
                          obj.saveObj6(...);
                          obj.saveObj7(...);
                          listsaveobj.add(obj); but it's not possible? */
                     }
        }
```

Comment: Would you consider replacing those seven fields with an array?

Comment: hi David, Yes, definitely :)

Comment: What are you splitting on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better way to extract the data:

```
String s = "001>10102011>874837>Y>Y>TEST001>No\\\\002>11102011>8743834>Y>Y>null>No\\\\";
String[] rows = s.split("\\\\");
for (String r : rows) {
    String[] cols = r.split(">");
    for (String c : cols) {
        System.out.print(c + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `s.split("\\\\\\\\")` on the second line?

Comment: Umm, don't let the ? at the end of my comment deceive you.  I wasn't really asking you.  `split` takes a regular expression as an argument.  The regular expression to match a backslash is two backslashes together, but you need four to write it in your code.  Since OP is using a pair of backslashes as a separator, you need eight to write it.

Comment: Hi David, what do you mean? I am using "\\" as an indicator for a new object.

Comment: What I mean is that Rendon's solution, as given, doesn't work.  You need to change the second line to `String[] rows = s.split("\\\\\\\\");` if you want to use two backslashes as a separator.

Comment: @rendon is it possible to do this on 2D Array?

Comment: @DavidWallace you are right. It gives different row numbers when I use "\\" and "\\\\\\\\". Thanks.